# Let vs run when it comes to check null

Tags: kotlin

I've noticed most people use `object?.let {}` for checking if something is null.
But why they chose `let` instead of `run` ? We can achieve exactly the same using `object?.run {}`
I know only difference is `this` and `it` inside the scope, but it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

You said it : the difference comes from "this" and "it" !

Everybody uses `let` for a good reason : `run` should be used when you want to return something, just like `let`, where `apply` or `also` return the object it was called on.

But then, what is the difference between `run` and `let` ? Well, `run` should be used when you treat mostly the object as a receiver, on which you want to call a bunch of methods : as `this` can be used implicitely, it's faster to write and easier to read.

But when the object is used as a value, then `let` is preferable, because the value is named `it`, which is shorter to use as a value (2 letters instead of 4), but more importantly, it is more readable ! Try reading :

`myComputationThatMightReturnNull()?.let { it * 2 }`

and

`myComputationThatMightReturnNull()?.run { this * 2 }`

The first one sounds more like spoken english, where the second is longer and more difficult to understand.

Because often the nullable value is used as... a value when it isn't `null`, let is most likely to be used in this case than run. But don't be afraid to use the latter when it seems right to you to do so, it's just a rule of thumb.